# Pie chart using only values of a certain group

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-charts

```
Asset Type   Amount  Value

EUR   FIAT   0.43   0.4577449106
USD   FIAT   0  0
SC1   Crypto 190.37 50.64
SC2   Crypto 776.3  14.04
SC3   Crypto 4.9    10.51
SC4   Crypto 70 70.15
SC5   Crypto 155    39.50
SC6   Crypto 680    38.1142304
SC7   Crypto 0.62   15.7643779
SC8   Crypto 50.00  56.25312541
Gold  Resource  10.50   441.665
```

I want to createa a pie chart that ONLY uses the values of type `crypto`, and not `gold` or `fiat` (and others). Is this possible? I didn't find a way without increasing the number of rows, which would not be a nice idea imho, just for a chart to being able to display the data.

The chart should show all `crypto` assets and their percentage in the overall crypto share. I want to see how much "value" each crypto has from the whole pool, as percentage. So SC1 would be like 20% of the whole portfolio, SC2 only 7%, etc.

I would like to have a pie chart for this.

Here is a visualisation if it is unclear what I try to ask for:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the only way is to filter it out with:

```
=FILTER(A:D, B:B="crypto")
```

and then use that for pie chart

Comment: Yeah I tested the filter on the chart directly already, that did not work. I really have to do a separate column for each row for data that doesn't add anything valuable other than serving that pie chart algorithm, right?

Comment: yes. charts does not support formulas directly so everything needs to be done with helper columns

Comment: You could try to do an [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) function to update the ranges of the chart filtering for that range. Are you used to Apps script? Could this solution work for you?